# rxJS - Close oberservable from source

Tags: node.js, typescript, rxjs

New to using rxJS and trying to close an observable from the source. There will be a dynamic number of events sent, I can't use a `take` filter to automatically unsubscribe based on a static count. How can the source of the observable tell all subscribers that the stream is closed, but allow all subscribers to finish processing any async messages in the pipe? I tried to use a second Subject object that will send an event when the source is closed, but it doesn't allow the events to process in the pipe, it causes immediate unsubscription.

TYIA!

Here is this code:

```
const source = new Observable<MessageToConsume<Mention>>((subscriber) => {
    return () => {
        console.log("complete called");
    };
});

for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    source.next(i);
}

source.complete();
// how to tell subscriber there is no more message to consume, time to unsubscribe
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to do anything. Each observable will close its subscription if the source completes.

If you need to do something when the source observable completes, you can put an object with `{next: (v) => void, complete: () => void}` and react to it.

See this code example ([and here a link to the playground](https://playcode.io/1526676))

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

const source$$ = new Subject();

const observer1 = source$$.subscribe({
  next: v => console.log('observer1 next', v),
  complete: v => console.log('observer1 complete')
})
const observer2 = source$$.subscribe({
  next: v => console.log('observer2 next', v),
  complete: v => console.log('observer2 complete')
})
const observer3 = source$$.subscribe({
  next: v => console.log('observer3 next', v),
  complete: v => console.log('observer3 complete')
})

console.log('observer1 closed?', observer1.closed)
console.log('observer2 closed?', observer2.closed)
console.log('observer3 closed?', observer3.closed)

source$$.next('a');
source$$.next('b');
source$$.complete()

console.log('observer1 closed?', observer1.closed)
console.log('observer2 closed?', observer2.closed)
console.log('observer3 closed?', observer3.closed)
```

will output

```
observer1 closed? false
observer2 closed? false
observer3 closed? false

observer1 next a
observer2 next a
observer3 next a

observer1 next b
observer2 next b
observer3 next b

observer1 complete
observer2 complete
observer3 complete

observer1 closed? true
observer2 closed? true
observer3 closed? true
```